# Zipping files with javascript - corrupt archive

Tags: javascript, cordova, compression

I'm trying to use [JSZip](http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/) to zip some text and then open it with [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). The problem is, the archive is apparently corrupted at some point. I can't open it. I'm guessing it's not created correctly, possibly because I'm not using the correct encoding,  but there could also be a slight chance that it's happening during transfer from my Android device (this is a [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com) project) to my PC (I use adb to transfer the archive).

My code is:

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.add("hi.txt", "Hello World");
var content = zip.generate(true); // true == get raw byte string
writer.write(content);
```

Where `writer` is a Phonegap [FileWriter](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently impossible to write binary data with Phonegap's FileWriter, as stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/p-9nCyn7vDI) by a PhoneGap guy.

Comment: This post is a few years old, and I'm having the same problem. Do you know of another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the same problem I've documented here
[document generation only works the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905696/document-generation-only-works-the-first-time)

In my case the document generation works fine when having the remote debugger attached.
In addition I can reproduce only on Android 4.4 (kitkat)